# How to hand sketch the parametric curve $y=\sin3t$ and $x=\cos t$?

Tags: curves, parametric

I tried to eliminate the variable $t$ and I've got 
$y = \sin(t)(4x^2-1)$
I know what it looks like by plotting with computer. but how do i do it by hand?

Comment: Your elimination of the parameter wasn't complete.

$y = \sin 3t = \sin(2t + t) = \sin 2t \cos t + \cos 2t \sin t = 2\sin t \cos^2 t + (2 \cos^2 t - 1) \sin t = \pm 2x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}\pm (2x^2-1)\sqrt{1-x^2} = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}(4x^2-1)$.

Still looks like quite a pain though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can go further to obtain $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}(4x^2 - 1)$ noting $\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}$. If you are patient to get $y'$ and $y''$ then you can sketch the graph by monotonicity and convexity of $y$.